# actionscript 3 as3 flash AIR font embed external

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

```
[Embed(source='/assets/calibri.ttf', fontName="Font", mimeType="application/x-font-truetype" embedAsCFF="false")]
private static var calibri:String;
```

I Looking from tutorial and get code like above and look like it's must on Class?
can I use it without class? or maybe an example for font loaded class please?

Answer (score 0):

Use the embed param `fontFamily`. This string you can use to set the font.

```
[Embed(source='/assets/calibri.ttf', fontFamily="calibri", mimeType="application/x-font-truetype" embedAsCFF="false")]
var CalibriFont:Class;

var tf:TextField = new TextField();    
tf.embedFonts = true;
addChild(tf);

var tff:TextFormat = new TextFormat();           
tff.font = "calibri";

tf.defaultTextFormat = tff;
tf.htmlText = "HELLO";
```

Comment: i got some error "unable to resolve 'Dosis-Regular.ttf' for transcoding"

Comment: Further the path has to be relative to the src-folder. Maybe `../assets/your-font.ttf`...